# How to install libaries in Linux

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu

I have a compiled [Criterion](https://github.com/Snaipe/Criterion/releases) library downloaded, and in main folder there is include, lib and share folder. Where to copy that, in order to work?

Comment: `sudo make install`

Comment: `/usr/local/` tends to be a default place for third party installed software. Alternatively, set your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to the lib directory, and you're generally good to go.

Comment: `meson install` doesn't work?

Comment: any where you want, as long as you know where they are.  I tend to use /opt of /home/<uname>/bin for stuff like this.  Lets say you dump things in /opt/criterion/include (and /opt/criterion/lin, /opt/criterion/share).  When you compile your project would would need to add "-I/opt/criterion/include" to you command line (assuming gcc or clang) so the compiler could find the header files.  You would also need to add "-L /opt/criterion/lib -l criterion" so the linker can find the libraries you need (assuming the library's name is libcriterion.x.x.x.so.  The build script should have an install

Comment: target to take care of this for you.  Also, make sure the permissions are set correctly so you can read those files.